# Jenkins Pipeline approval by clicking a button in email

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way that user could approve the Jenkins pipeline input from email?

```
 Hi
 There is a Deployment for build #####
 Please click on Approve(this should be a approval link) or Reject(this should be some rejection link)
```

Instead of user clicking on the Build URL and then going there and clicking on approve or abort

Is it possible in Jenkins Pipeline? 
currently i tried buildurl/input/approve and buildurl/input/abort but those doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try something with triggering remote builds for your job .You can make a central file which is placed at an accessible server and you could hit that url with your parameters .Check this page for more info:
https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/2654